# How to make the post request in BOX API using LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, rest, lwp

I have tried the following code

```
my $url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/users/";

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent; 
use HTTP::Request::Common qw{ POST };
use CGI;

my $ua      = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request = POST( $url, [ 'name' => 'mkhun', 'is_platform_access_only' => 'true',"Authorization" => "Bearer <ACC TOK>" ] );
my $content = $ua->request($request)->as_string();

my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header(), $content;
```

The above code always give the 400 error. And throwing the

```
{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"entity-body","message":"Invalid value 'is_platform_access_only=true&Authorization=Bearer+WcpZasitJWVDQ87Vs1OB9dQedRVyOrs6&name=mkhun'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name\/value pair"}]},
```

I don't know what is the issue. The same thing with Linux curl is working.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
-d '{"name": "Ned Stark", "is_platform_access_only": true}' \
-X POST
```

Comment: `true` and `'true'` don't mean the same thing. `[ ... ]` and `{ ... }` are not interchangeable.

Comment: @SinanÜnür `[` `]` and `{` `}` are mostly interchangeable when it comes to posting form data with LWP.

Comment: @melpomene You are assuming that the software on the receiving side does not care about the order in which parameters are specified. Unlikely, sure, but not unimaginable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Box API documentation says](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#section-inputoutput-format):

> Both request body data and response data are formatted as [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Your code is sending [form-encoded data](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-$url) instead.

Also, it looks like `Authorization` is supposed to be an HTTP header, not a form field.

Try this instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON::PP;

my $url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/users/";
my $payload = {
    name => 'mkhun',
    is_platform_access_only => \1,
};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->post(
    $url,
    Authorization => 'Bearer <TOKEN>',
    Content => encode_json($payload),
);
```

Comment: Thanks. From a long time I'm trying. Actually, I want the solution with PHP so I was risen the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481851/post-the-data-with-header-in-curl-not-working-in-php/45487040#45487040) in PHP tag but I didn't get the result. But after decoding it is working thanks.